# Creating an alphabetic list with repetitions that skips every other character

Tags: r

I am trying to create a `character` list in R as such:

`[a, a, c, c, e, e, ..., y, y]`

but the closest thing I have been able to achieve is a `numeric` list with the indices of the characters in the `letters` list:

`[1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5,..., 25, 25]`

by using:

```
rep(seq(1, 26, 2), each = 2)
```

Is there a way that I can replace the elements in my list with the corresponding character in `letters`? Or even a better way to achieve this result?

Comment: `letters[rep(seq(1, 26, 2), each = 2)]`

Comment: `rep(letters[c(TRUE, FALSE)], each = 2)`

Comment: @LyzandeR of course! Thank you :)

Comment: @d.b that's quite an interesting solution. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Why not have a little bit more fun? `letters[rep(1:26, e = 2)[which((rep(1:26,e=2) %% 2) == 1)]]`